# Why does my remarketing audience in Google Analytics show 0 eligible audience?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, remarketing

I have defined a new custom audience (my first one) to make available as a remarketing list in my connected AdWords account. I see that my parameters show 1,450 active users that match the conditions within the past 7 days. When I save the audience, the text at the bottom of the audience summary reads:

> Display audience size: 0
>
> Search audience size: 0

Additionally, when I select this audience as the audience for a remarketing campaign in AdWords, it says there are "too few people on your remarketing list."

What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only just created the list it will take some time to populate; whilst it forecasts how many people would have been added over the past 7 days, it won't add people retrospectively. Only people from this point on who match the criteria would be added. By the sounds of it your list should become active in a few days.

Comment: Very good to know. I read all of the "Learn more..." links that I came across; I'm sure this delay is discussed somewhere, but I didn't come across it. All of the configuring, wondering, waiting, and re-configuring gets a bit frustrating.